# Deserialize array with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, servicestack

Here's what I'm trying to post to my ServiceStack web service:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8092/profiles',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        FirstName : "John",
        LastName : "Doe",
        Categories : [ "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3" ]
    },
    success: function (response) { $('#response').append('Success!'); },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status + ' Error: ' + thrownError);
      },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

And here's the destination class:

```
[Route("/profiles", "POST")]
public class ProfileRequest
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string[] Categories{ get; set; }
}
```

All the fields are being populated except for the array.  Can ServiceStack just not handle objects of this complexity or am I missing something?

**Note**:  I've seen [Unable to deserialize array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602548/unable-to-deserialize-array)  which suggests using JSON.stringify() but that solution still doesn't seem to work, in fact it makes it worse by causing no data to be deserialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack can handle this, but your jQuery `$.ajax` data has to be JSON stringified using the `JSON.stringify()` method and set the `contentType` to `application/json` otherwise jQuery will try posting the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and deserialising will fail.

So your request should be:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8092/profiles',
    type:'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName: "Doe",
        Categories: [ "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3" ]
    }),
    success: function (response) { $('#response').append('Success!'); },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status + ' Error: ' + thrownError);
      },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the things I had already tried, but it resulted in no data getting deserialized, not just the array.

Comment: It looks like I'm using 3.9.56.0

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work.  Looking at my C# objects all of the values are just null.  If I remove the JSON.stringify() everything populates except for the array.

Comment: @SethMoore Okay I have setup a test project and got it to work. You need to set `contentType: "application/json"` then it works.

Comment: Now that gives me the error "EndpointHandlerBase|Error occured while Processing Request: Could not find method named Options(ProfileRequest) or Any(ProfileRequest) on Service ProfileController"

Comment: @SethMoore That's because you must be using CORS which you haven't configured properly. If you set your url to be `url: '/profiles'` and make the request to the same host it works. Otherwise you will need to configure CORS.

Comment: I think something must be wrong with my ajax call because I sent the stringified profile with Chrome's Advanced REST Client plugin and it worked just fine.  If that's the case I'm not too worried, the ajax call was just to test the service.