# Unable to deserialize array via GET

Tags: c#, jquery, json, kendo-ui, servicestack

I am using Kendo UI's [DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverSorting) to send sorting information to my ServiceStack service.  I know that this [has been addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602548/unable-to-deserialize-array) if you're using using `POST`, but I want to adhere to RESTful designs, so the request verb needs to be `GET`.  I'm using this snippet to test with:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverSorting: true,
        sort: [{ field: "ProductName", dir: "desc" },
               { field: "Category", dir: "asc"}],

        serverPaging: true,
        page: 2,
        pageSize: 5,

        transport: {

            read: {
                url: "/products",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            },

            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                //return kendo.stringify(data);
                //return JSON.stringify(data);
                //return $.param(data, true);
                //data.sort = kendo.stringify(data.sort);
                return data;
            }
        }
    });

    dataSource.fetch(function () {
        console.log(dataSource.view());
    });
```

The sorting parameters get turned into a jagged array like:

```
sort[0][field]: ProductName
sort[0][dir]: desc
sort[1][field]: Category
sort[1][dir]: asc
```

My request DTO is:

```
    public class SortTerm
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}

public class KendoQuery
{

    public List<SortTerm> Sort { get; set; }

    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

All of the simple parameters get deserialized, but how on earth can I transform the `Sort` property, either client-side or server-side, to have it populate correctly?

Notice that I've tried a variety of serialization techniques in the `parameterMap` function and I'm completely stumped.

**EDIT**

So this all boils down to:  How do I pass an array of objects via $.get() to a ServiceStack service, when jQuery thoughtfully rearranges my request into a jagged array?  This stinks of a request filter, but I have to imagine its been solved before for `**GET**` requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use complex data structures, such as that of the jagged sorting array, with a `GET` request using standard techniques because JSON `GET` requests only support simple variables as these can be translated to request parameters in the query string. So the request will form correctly for the simple parameters `?Page=2&PageSize=5 ...` but for `sort[0][field]` this cannot be specified as a query string request parameter.

However you could work around this if you where to stringify your search criteria object using [`datasource.transport.parameterMap`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) so that it can be passed as a parameter, which is then converted at the server.

```js
parameterMap: function (data, type) {
    // Convert the search criteria to a JSON string and store it on value sortJson
    data.sortJson = JSON.stringify(data.sort);

    // Remove the sort value, as this will be provided by sortJson
    delete data.sort;

    // Return the data
    return data
}
```

At the server you will need to handle converting the JSON string to the `List<SortTerm>`:

```cs
public class KendoQuery
{

    List<SortTerm> sort;
    public List<SortTerm> Sort {
         get {
             // Handles deserialising the SortJson value 
             if(sort == null)
                 sort = ServiceStack.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<SortTerm>>(SortJson);
             return sort;
         }
    }

    public string SortJson { get; set; } 
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The overall reason I was wiffing out was, as you said, that GET just can't reasonably pass complex data structures.  Though I said either client- or server-side fix would be fine, I am preferring server-side to keep the client-side code clean, and back-end agnostic.  I've posted my code in the answer below.

Comment: @jklemmack Yeah that's reasonable about keeping the client side clean where possible so your solution looks appropriate too (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Scott's answer above is the right one, but here is my more server-centric solution.  Basically, I manually reconstruct the `SortTerm` object from the query string.  This is extendable to the other Kendo-specific parameters, like Filters & Groups.

**Client-code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverSorting: true,
            sort: [{ field: "ProductName", dir: "desc" },
                   { field: "Category", dir: "asc" }],

            serverPaging: true,
            page: 2,
            pageSize: 5,

            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/products",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });

        dataSource.fetch(function () {
            console.log(dataSource.view());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server code (in AppHost implementation)**:

```
this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, resp, dto) =>
{
    if (dto is KendoQueryBase)
    {
        KendoQueryBase qb = dto as KendoQueryBase;
        if (qb.Sort == null) qb.Sort = new List<SortTerm>();
        Dictionary<string, string> qs = req.QueryString.ToDictionary();
        var i = 0;
        while (qs.ContainsKey("sort[{0}][field]".Fmt(i)))
        {
            qb.Sort.Add(new SortTerm()
            {
                field = qs["sort[{0}][field]".Fmt(i)],
                dir = qs["sort[{0}][dir]".Fmt(i)]
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
});
```